# PHP: Split arrays

Tags: php, arrays, key, html-entities

I am still a beginner and I need some help.
I've got an array like this;

```
$_POST=

Array ( [0] => aaa@gmail.com [1] => bbb [2] => ccc [3] => ddd [4] => eee [5] => fff [6] => ggg [7] => hhh [8] => iii [9] => jjj [10] => 31 [11] => k )
```

I want to split the elements up into keys and values, and then get the values and put it into an array.

Then I want to put htmlentities around each value like this:

```
foreach (something as something){

echo "htmlentities(".$valuearray.")";
}
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this code does is create an `associative array` with keys and values. Then we loop through and push values in to the `values array`.

We also use `htmlentities` on each value which is pushed.

If we `echo` first element in the values array it will display `value1`.

```
<?php
$arr = [
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2"
];

$valuesArr = [];

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    array_push($valuesArr, htmlentities($value));
}
?>
```

What you can do is replace my array with your array and change the names in the `foreach` loop if you need too.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($something as $key => $val){
  $a[] = $val;
}

var_dump($a);
```

Try this code. It will get only the values of that array.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function such as `htmlentities()` to the values of an array by using `array_map`:

```
$escapedArray = array_map('htmlentities', $_POST);
```

PHP documentation: [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)