# PHP array and htmlentities

Tags: php, arrays, key, entities

```
$_POST=

Array ( [0] => aaa@gmail.com [1] => bbb [2] => ccc [3] => ddd [4] => eee [5] => fff [6] => ggg [7] => hhh [8] => iii [9] => jjj [10] => 31 [11] => k )

foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
    for ($key = 0; $key <= 9;$key++){
        $_POST2[$val] = htmlentities($_POST[$val]);
    }
}
}
```

This is my code and what I was trying to do was that I wanted to split the `$_POST` array into `$key` and `$val`. Then I wanted to tell the program that as the `$key` goes up by `1`, put `htmlentities()` around the `$val`.
Can you please help me? I have been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: Seems pretty similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31868775/3933332 Don't you think too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this wrong way. Try with -

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
    $_POST2[] = htmlentities([$val]);
}
```

No need for that `for` loop. `foreach` will wrap all the values. And if you want the `key`s to be same as `$_POST` then just leave it empty.

update 18.11.2019

---

In fact if you are dealing with a associative arrays such as _POST (as opposition to indexed arrays) where you are dealing with keys that have a name, and not with numbers, then you must write the code like this:

```
// this is the classic orthodox syntax 
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
  $_POST[$key] = htmlentities($val);
}
```

If want to leave out the `$key` like suggested by my friend in the upper side it will work, but you will end up having a combined array that is associative AND indexed the same time (using double memory and tremendously slowing down your script). And what is more important it will not change the associative part, it will produce and append the indexed array that has been modified by `htmlentities`.

```
// appends a indexed array
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
  $_POST[] = htmlentities($val);
}

// The & in front of $val permits me to modify the value of $val
// inside foreach, without appending a indexed array:

foreach($_POST as &$val){
  $val = htmlentities($val);
}
```

If you work with indexed array you can always leave the `$key` out, but please also note that it is `htmlentities($val)` and not `htmlentities([$val])`.

Comment: And you probably want to directly thr post array itself, even if what you're doing is an antipattern, you should do the htmlentities in your view, you should have your xss in your db and then filter it in the view because you should want ti easly change the rapresentation of your data and for example in a 2nd rel. You could have a json representation

Comment: *even if what you're doing is an antipattern* - can you please explain? @LucaBruzzone

Comment: you shouldn't do an htmlentities on the input, your input are by definition not safe, is your model that needs to check if you're having an sqli and your view (or template system) that needs to do the htmlentities in order to filter all the data.
I didn't express mysqlf clearly, your solution is good, is the problem that is wrong xD

Comment: It is not using any `MVC`. And till now OP didn't mention anything about this or saving it to database or displaying somewhere else.

Comment: I know but still it's good to point it out, it's why I gave you the upvote and then commented to clearify xD
Even if it's not using mvc this is actually a bad practice XD