# Copying $_POST to a New (Superglobal) Variable

Tags: php, variables, global, superglobals

I am still a beginner, and I want to change all of my `$_POST` into `$_POST2` using a global/superglobal variable. Please help.

Comment: [you can't do that `$_POST2` it's a superglobal, end of story.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Comment: **your answer is up there ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^**

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: [**RTFM**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Comment: question is: why? that's a core function. download the core and modify it; might work lol anything to do with your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/31870612/

Comment: If you want to **change** it, that cannot be done, as others are saying. If you want to make a copy of `$_POST` that's different. But why would you want to?

Comment: Like @Fred -ii- is asking, I wonder why you would want to do this. I have never seen any situation in which this would be appropriate/necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a copy of `$_POST` and call it `$_POST2`, you can. When copying an array, PHP will make a copy rather than a reference. However, if the array contains *objects*, those objects will be references to the same old object, rather than clones.

If you really need to copy it:

```
$_POST2 = $_POST;
```

Another important note is that `$_POST` is a [*superglobal*](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), and your "copy" will not be. The only way to access it without a `global $_POST2` would be to reference it via the `$GLOBALS` superglobal.

```
echo($GLOBALS['_POST2']['my_var']);
```

This solution, however, smells of an architectural problem. I'm sure there are other, better ways to solve this, perhaps involving Object Oriented Programming concepts.

Comment: I won't you're not in for a long ride ;-)